# Flutter App APK error : '[FATAL:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(89)] Error while initializing the Dart VM:Precompiled runtime requires snapshot

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build.gradle, apk

I have generated the Apk file and installed in mobile and app get crashed when open. This the error i see in logs when app crash

> 2023-09-12 11:09:20.421 726-881/? E/qdmetadata: paramType 2048 not supported
> 2023-09-12 11:09:20.430 19458-19458/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
> 2023-09-12 11:09:20.430 19458-19458/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/laurel_sprout/laurel_sprout:11/RKQ1.200903.002/V12.0.26.0.RFQMIXM:user/release-keys'
> 2023-09-12 11:09:20.430 19458-19458/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
> 2023-09-12 11:09:20.430 19458-19458/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
> 2023-09-12 11:09:20.433 19458-19458/? A/DEBUG: Timestamp: 2023-09-12 11:09:20+0530
> 2023-09-12 11:09:20.433 19458-19458/? A/DEBUG: pid: 19266, tid: 19266, name:  >>>  <<<
> 2023-09-12 11:09:20.433 19458-19458/? A/DEBUG: uid: 10285
> 2023-09-12 11:09:20.433 19458-19458/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
> 2023-09-12 11:09:20.433 19458-19458/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: '[FATAL:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(89)] Error while initializing the Dart VM: Precompiled runtime requires a precompiled snapshot'
>
> this are the plugins used in project
> http: ^0.13.5
> permission_handler: ^10.2.0
> shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
> background_fetch: ^1.1.6
> uuid: ^3.0.7
> intl: ^0.18.1
> flutter_typeahead: ^4.1.1
> multi_select_flutter: ^4.1.3
> url_launcher: ^6.1.7
> firebase_analytics: ^10.4.4
> cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
> sqflite: ^2.2.0+3
> path_provider: ^2.0.11
> expansion_tile_card: ^3.0.0
> table_calendar: ^3.0.8
> image_picker: ^0.8.6
> flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.3
> substring_highlight: ^1.0.33
> flutter_local_notifications: ^15.1.0+1
> timezone: ^0.9.0
> geolocator: ^9.0.2
> internet_connection_checker: ^1.0.0+1
> multiselect: ^0.0.4
> flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.11.0
> rxdart: ^0.27.5
> flutter_native_timezone: ^2.0.0
> firebase_core: ^2.15.0
> firebase_crashlytics: ^3.3.4
> package_info_plus: ^4.1.0
> map_launcher: ^2.5.0
> regexpattern: ^2.5.0
> custom_radio_group_list: ^1.0.0
> firebase_messaging: ^14.6.5
> device_info_plus: ^8.2.0
> android_id: ^0.3.3
> fluttercontactpicker: ^4.7.0
> in_app_update: ^4.2.0

this is the code in main.dart file

```
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();


 await Firebase.initializeApp(
name: "distrigoboost",
options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
 final _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
 final _messageStreamController = BehaviorSubject<RemoteMessage>();
 SharedPreferencesHelper.init();
await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(
  alert: true,
  announcement: true,
  badge: true,
  carPlay: true,
  criticalAlert: false,
  provisional: false,
  sound: true);
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(handleBackgroundMessage);
```

Can you please help me to fix this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: how did you "generate the Apk"? what exact command did you use?

Comment: @pskink I have opened android folder separately in android studio and generated signed apk file from build sections, bebug Apk file is working when i build apk in release mode its happen

Comment: Please share your main method.

Comment: Hi @DholaSain, i have update the question with code used in main method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried every solutions to fix this issue but nothing worked, At last i have deleted my android folder and created again using the below command

```
flutter create . --platforms=android
```

And added all the changes back to the android folder which are done before step by step and it worked for me